# Extract YAFFS filesystem from binary

Tags: linux, firmware

Iv got firmware from vivax set-top box backed up on flash drive and I vould like to change splash screen on it. The firmware seem to be yaffs but I cant extract files in order to change something.

```
:~$ binwalk usb_backup_upgrade.bin 

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
27288         0x6A98          SHA256 hash constants, little endian
69888         0x11100         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 1059144 bytes
462876        0x7101C         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 7916292 bytes
```

when I extract usb_backup_upgrade.bin Iv got 4 files

```
_usb_backup_upgrade.bin.extracted$ ls
11100  11100.7z  7101C  7101C.7z  _7101C.extracted
```

First 11100

```
$ binwalk 11100

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
7812          0x1E84          JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01
8058          0x1F7A          Unix path: /www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
8220          0x201C          Unix path: /ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/g/img/">
25303         0x62D7          Unix path: /kfdf9k2R8cMvysvJWg/5xP/ADLSzurWTVNMMU/p&#xA;yJFHeXSRevE1EkljNowk4xSSqv2SC1a0qrPjhfyslWy/5xX/ADLgUxTX+iT27U9SGSa5dGoQRVWt&#xA;qH
27374         0x6AEE          Unix path: /ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/mm/"
27432         0x6B28          Unix path: /ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/sType/ResourceRef#"
27505         0x6B71          Unix path: /ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/sType/ResourceEvent#"
27580         0x6BBC          Unix path: /ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/sType/ManifestItem#">
38474         0x964A          Unix path: /purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
772652        0xBCA2C         U-Boot version string, "U-Boot 1.1.6 (Jan 16 2015 - 02:23:52)"
777583        0xBDD6F         POSIX tar archive, owner user name: "s", owner group name: "o_cmd"
```

and second

```
$ binwalk 7101C

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             eCos kernel exception handler, architecture: MIPSEL, exception vector table base address: 0x80558540
640           0x280           eCos kernel exception handler, architecture: MIPSEL, exception vector table base address: 0x80558540
4307602       0x41BA92        Unix path: /../../HB/app/tv/appTvVideo_dvb.c
4389070       0x42F8CE        Unix path: /../../HB/app/zapper/appZapper.c
4391820       0x43038C        CRC32 polynomial table, little endian
4392970       0x43080A        Unix path: /../../HB/app/main/appMain.c
4393342       0x43097E        Unix path: /../../HB/app/main/appWDT.c
4393574       0x430A66        Unix path: /../../HB/app/menu/MApp_Menu.c
4393758       0x430B1E        Unix path: /../../HB/app/menu/MApp_MenuChannel.c
4397102       0x43182E        Unix path: /../../HB/app/monitor/appMonitor.c
4398262       0x431CB6        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/api/font/apiVectorFont.c
4398414       0x431D4E        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/api/zui/MApp_ZUI_APIcontrols.c
4398666       0x431E4A        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/api/zui/MApp_ZUI_APIgdi.c
4398882       0x431F22        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/api/zui/MApp_ZUI_APIwindow.c
4399178       0x43204A        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/api/zui/MApp_ZUI_Main.c
4399302       0x4320C6        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/api/zui/apiMvf_base.c
4399654       0x432226        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/api/zui/apiMvf_grays.c
4401186       0x432822        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/api/database/MApp_SaveData.c
4401744       0x432A50        CRC32 polynomial table, little endian
4402906       0x432EDA        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/api/database/apiDTVDataManager.c
4404518       0x433526        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/api/chscan/apiChScan.c
4405394       0x433892        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/api/EPG_Swap_DB/apiEPG_DB.c
4408198       0x434386        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/api/EPG_Swap_DB/apiEPG_EIT_Swap.c
4410158       0x434B2E        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/driver/pq/drvPQ.c
4413646       0x4358CE        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/driver/pq/hal/kriti_mstar/include/QualityMap_BW.c
4414022       0x435A46        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/driver/pq/hal/kriti_mstar/mhal_pq.c
4415066       0x435E5A        Unix path: /../../HB/app/media/appMM_Browser.c
4416158       0x43629E        Unix path: /../../HB/app/media/appPVR_playback.c
4416918       0x436596        Unix path: /../../HB/app/media/MMfilesystem/apiFSUtil.c
4417234       0x4366D2        Unix path: /../../HB/app/media/portinglayer/mm/src/porting_audio.c
4425946       0x4388DA        Unix path: /../../HB/app/media/vdplayerV2/appMM_playback.c
4426570       0x438B4A        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/zui/MApp_ZUI_ACTglobal.c
4427538       0x438F12        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/zui/MApp_ZUI_GDISetup.c
4427974       0x4390C6        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/zui/widgets/MApp_ZUI_CTLsolidprogressbar.c
4428226       0x4391C2        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/zui/pagedoc/MApp_PvrZapper.c
4428446       0x43929E        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/zui/pagedoc/MApp_Pvrv3.c
4438850       0x43BB42        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/zui/pageview/MApp_ZUI_ACTAudioLanguage.c
4439082       0x43BC2A        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/zui/pageview/MApp_ZUI_ACTChannelInfo.c
4440318       0x43C0FE        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/zui/pageview/MApp_ZUI_ACTMediaMoviePlay.c
4441950       0x43C75E        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/zui/pageview/MApp_ZUI_ACTMediaPlay.c
4442178       0x43C842        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/zui/pageview/MApp_ZUI_ACTMediaSimpleStart_PVR.c
4443290       0x43CC9A        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/zui/pageview/MApp_ZUI_ACTMenuPvrDevice.c
4444006       0x43CF66        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/zui/pageview/MApp_ZUI_ACTPvrSubtitleLanguage.c
4444586       0x43D1AA        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/zui/pageview/MApp_ZUI_ACTSubtitle.c
4445218       0x43D422        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/zui/pageview/MApp_ZUI_ACTbookmanage.c
4445966       0x43D70E        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/zui/pageview/MApp_ZUI_ACTprogedit.c
4447410       0x43DCB2        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/zui/pageview/MApp_ZUI_ACTtvbanner.c
4448530       0x43E112        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/zui/pageview/MApp_ZUI_ACTtvfavoritelist.c
4448774       0x43E206        Unix path: /../../HB/platform/zui/pageview/MApp_ZUI_Utility.c
5003844       0x4C5A44        Unix path: /ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/Kappa/LIB_eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/kernel/s
5003845       0x4C5A45        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/Kappa/LIB_eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/kernel/sm"
5003875       0x4C5A63        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/Kappa/LIB_eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/kernel/smp.hxx"
5003893       0x4C5A75        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/kernel/smp.hxx"
5003981       0x4C5ACD        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/Kappa/LIB_eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/memalloc/"
5004011       0x4C5AEB        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/Kappa/LIB_eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/memalloc/mempolt2.inl"
5004029       0x4C5AFD        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/memalloc/mempolt2.inl"
5004125       0x4C5B5D        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/services/memalloc/common/v2_0_60/src/malloc.cxx"
5004155       0x4C5B7B        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/services/memalloc/common/v2_0_60/src/malloc.cxx"
5004221       0x4C5BBD        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/io/fileio/v2_0_60/src/misc.cxx"
5004251       0x4C5BDB        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/io/fileio/v2_0_60/src/misc.cxx"
5004333       0x4C5C2D        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/fs/fat/v2_0_60/src/fatfs_supp.c"
5004363       0x4C5C4B        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/fs/fat/v2_0_60/src/fatfs_supp.c"
5005580       0x4C610C        Unix path: /ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/fs/fat/v2_0_60/src/fatfs_ncache.c
5005581       0x4C610D        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/fs/fat/v2_0_60/src/fatfs_ncache.c"
5005611       0x4C612B        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/fs/fat/v2_0_60/src/fatfs_ncache.c"
5005940       0x4C6274        Unix path: /ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/fs/fat/v2_0_60/src/fatfs_blib.c
5005941       0x4C6275        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/fs/fat/v2_0_60/src/fatfs_blib.c"
5005971       0x4C6293        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/fs/fat/v2_0_60/src/fatfs_blib.c"
5006676       0x4C6554        Unix path: /ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/io/disk/v2_0_60/src/disk.c
5006677       0x4C6555        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/io/disk/v2_0_60/src/disk.c"
5006707       0x4C6573        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/io/disk/v2_0_60/src/disk.c"
5008348       0x4C6BDC        Unix path: /ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/hal/common/v2_0_60/src/hal_misc.c
5008349       0x4C6BDD        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/hal/common/v2_0_60/src/hal_misc.c"
5008379       0x4C6BFB        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/hal/common/v2_0_60/src/hal_misc.c"
5008609       0x4C6CE1        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCos][CPU INFO] : CPU Clock = %d : RTC Period = %d"
5009060       0x4C6EA4        Unix path: /ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/kernel/v2_0_60/src/common/clock.cxx
5009061       0x4C6EA5        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/kernel/v2_0_60/src/common/clock.cxx"
5009091       0x4C6EC3        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/kernel/v2_0_60/src/common/clock.cxx"
5009409       0x4C7001        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/kernel/v2_0_60/src/common/kapi.cxx"
5009439       0x4C701F        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/kernel/v2_0_60/src/common/kapi.cxx"
5009493       0x4C7055        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/Kappa/LIB_eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/kernel/th"
5009523       0x4C7073        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/Kappa/LIB_eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/kernel/thread.inl"
5009541       0x4C7085        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/kernel/thread.inl"
5010176       0x4C7300        Unix path: /ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/kernel/v2_0_60/src/common/thread.cxx
5010177       0x4C7301        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/kernel/v2_0_60/src/common/thread.cxx"
5010207       0x4C731F        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/kernel/v2_0_60/src/common/thread.cxx"
5010465       0x4C7421        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/kernel/v2_0_60/src/common/except.cxx"
5010495       0x4C743F        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/kernel/v2_0_60/src/common/except.cxx"
5010684       0x4C74FC        Unix path: /ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/kernel/v2_0_60/src/intr/intr.cxx
5010685       0x4C74FD        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/kernel/v2_0_60/src/intr/intr.cxx"
5010715       0x4C751B        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/kernel/v2_0_60/src/intr/intr.cxx"
5011337       0x4C7789        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/kernel/v2_0_60/src/sched/mlqueue.cxx"
5011367       0x4C77A7        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/kernel/v2_0_60/src/sched/mlqueue.cxx"
5011925       0x4C79D5        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/kernel/v2_0_60/src/sched/sched.cxx"
5011955       0x4C79F3        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/kernel/v2_0_60/src/sched/sched.cxx"
5012620       0x4C7C8C        Unix path: /ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/kernel/v2_0_60/src/sync/cnt_sem.cxx
5012621       0x4C7C8D        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/kernel/v2_0_60/src/sync/cnt_sem.cxx"
5012651       0x4C7CAB        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/kernel/v2_0_60/src/sync/cnt_sem.cxx"
5012833       0x4C7D61        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/kernel/v2_0_60/src/sync/flag.cxx"
5012863       0x4C7D7F        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/kernel/v2_0_60/src/sync/flag.cxx"
5013293       0x4C7F2D        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/Kappa/LIB_eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/kernel/mb"
5013323       0x4C7F4B        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/Kappa/LIB_eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/kernel/mboxt2.inl"
5013341       0x4C7F5D        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/kernel/mboxt2.inl"
5014181       0x4C82A5        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/kernel/v2_0_60/src/sync/mutex.cxx"
5014211       0x4C82C3        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/kernel/v2_0_60/src/sync/mutex.cxx"
5014897       0x4C8571        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/services/memalloc/common/v2_0_60/src/dlmalloc.cxx"
5014927       0x4C858F        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/services/memalloc/common/v2_0_60/src/dlmalloc.cxx"
5015649       0x4C8861        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/language/c/libc/setjmp/v2_0_60/src/longjmp.cxx"
5015679       0x4C887F        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/language/c/libc/setjmp/v2_0_60/src/longjmp.cxx"
5015829       0x4C8915        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/Kappa/LIB_eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/libc/stdi"
5015859       0x4C8933        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/Kappa/LIB_eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/libc/stdio/stream.inl"
5015877       0x4C8945        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/libc/stdio/stream.inl"
5016101       0x4C8A25        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/language/c/libc/stdio/v2_0_60/src/common/stream.cxx"
5016131       0x4C8A43        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/language/c/libc/stdio/v2_0_60/src/common/stream.cxx"
5016201       0x4C8A89        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/Kappa/LIB_eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/libc/stdi"
5016231       0x4C8AA7        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/Kappa/LIB_eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/libc/stdio/streambuf.inl"
5016249       0x4C8AB9        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/libc/stdio/streambuf.inl"
5017624       0x4C9018        Unix path: /ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/language/c/libc/string/v2_0_60/src/strtok.cxx
5017625       0x4C9019        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/language/c/libc/string/v2_0_60/src/strtok.cxx"
5017655       0x4C9037        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/language/c/libc/string/v2_0_60/src/strtok.cxx"
5018041       0x4C91B9        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/io/fileio/v2_0_60/src/fd.cxx"
5018071       0x4C91D7        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/io/fileio/v2_0_60/src/fd.cxx"
5018177       0x4C9241        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/io/fileio/v2_0_60/src/file.cxx"
5018207       0x4C925F        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/io/fileio/v2_0_60/src/file.cxx"
5018605       0x4C93ED        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/io/fileio/v2_0_60/src/dir.cxx"
5018635       0x4C940B        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/io/fileio/v2_0_60/src/dir.cxx"
5018749       0x4C947D        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/io/fileio/v2_0_60/src/select.cxx"
5018779       0x4C949B        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/io/fileio/v2_0_60/src/select.cxx"
5018857       0x4C94E9        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/language/c/libc/startup/v2_0_60/src/main.cxx"
5018887       0x4C9507        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/language/c/libc/startup/v2_0_60/src/main.cxx"
5019141       0x4C9605        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/Kappa/LIB_eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/libc/stdi"
5019171       0x4C9623        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/Kappa/LIB_eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/libc/stdio/stdiofiles.inl"
5019189       0x4C9635        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/libc/stdio/stdiofiles.inl"
5020472       0x4C9B38        Unix path: /ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/language/c/libc/startup/v2_0_60/src/_exit.cxx
5020473       0x4C9B39        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/language/c/libc/startup/v2_0_60/src/_exit.cxx"
5020503       0x4C9B57        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/language/c/libc/startup/v2_0_60/src/_exit.cxx"
5020609       0x4C9BC1        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/language/c/libc/startup/v2_0_60/src/atexit.cxx"
5020639       0x4C9BDF        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/language/c/libc/startup/v2_0_60/src/atexit.cxx"
5021120       0x4C9DC0        Unix path: /ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/fs/ntfs/v2_0_60/src/attrib.c
5021121       0x4C9DC1        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/fs/ntfs/v2_0_60/src/attrib.c"
5021151       0x4C9DDF        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/fs/ntfs/v2_0_60/src/attrib.c"
5021876       0x4CA0B4        Unix path: /ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/fs/ntfs/v2_0_60/src/ntfs_blib.c
5021877       0x4CA0B5        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/fs/ntfs/v2_0_60/src/ntfs_blib.c"
5021907       0x4CA0D3        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/fs/ntfs/v2_0_60/src/ntfs_blib.c"
5033632       0x4CCEA0        Unix path: /home/mstar/PERFORCE/THEALE/utopia_release/UTPA-24.0.x_Kriti/project/kriti_ecos/../../mxlib/hal/kriti/audio/halAUDIO.c
5033707       0x4CCEEB        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos/../../mxlib/hal/kriti/audio/halAUDIO.c"
5038144       0x4CE040        Unix path: /home/stb/PERFORCE/THEALE/utopia_release/UTPA-24.0.x_Kriti/project/kriti_ecos/../../mxlib/hal/kriti/dac/halDAC.c
5038217       0x4CE089        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos/../../mxlib/hal/kriti/dac/halDAC.c"
5066028       0x4D4D2C        Unix path: /home/mstar/PERFORCE/THEALE/utopia_release/UTPA-24.0.x_Kriti/project/kriti_ecos/../../mxlib/hal/kriti/mvd/halMVD.c
5066103       0x4D4D77        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos/../../mxlib/hal/kriti/mvd/halMVD.c"
5091476       0x4DB094        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCos Newhost"
5108812       0x4DF44C        Unix path: /home/stb/PERFORCE/THEALE/utopia_release/UTPA-24.0.x_Kriti/project/kriti_ecos/../../mxlib/hal/kriti/ve/mhal_tvencoder.c
5108885       0x4DF495        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos/../../mxlib/hal/kriti/ve/mhal_tvencoder.c"
5109464       0x4DF6D8        Unix path: /home/franke.wu/workspace/THEALE/utopia_release/UTPA-24.0.x_Kriti/project/kriti_ecos/../../mxlib/msos/ecos/MsOS_ecos.c
5109544       0x4DF728        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos/../../mxlib/msos/ecos/MsOS_ecos.c"
5109566       0x4DF73E        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos/MsOS_ecos.c"
5109576       0x4DF748        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos.c"
5110012       0x4DF8FC        Unix path: /home/franke.wu/workspace/THEALE/utopia_release/UTPA-24.0.x_Kriti/project/kriti_ecos/../../mxlib/drv/miu/drvMIU.c
5110092       0x4DF94C        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos/../../mxlib/drv/miu/drvMIU.c"
5110300       0x4DFA1C        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos/../../mxlib/drv/sys/drvDMD_VD_MBX.c"
5304106       0x50EF2A        Unix path: /../src/si_v2/apiSI.c
5307730       0x50FD52        Unix path: /../src/dvb_subtitle/apiSubtitle_DC2_Decoder.c
5308386       0x50FFE2        Unix path: /../src/dvb_subtitle/apiSubtitle_Decoder.c
5403172       0x527224        CRC32 polynomial table, little endian
5407268       0x528224        CRC32 polynomial table, big endian
5428390       0x52D4A6        Unix path: /../src/mm/mapp_music.c
5431970       0x52E2A2        Unix path: /../src/espvr/apiEsPVR.cpp
5433930       0x52EA4A        Unix path: /../src/espvr/core/src/api/mapi_pvr_browser.cpp
5434774       0x52ED96        Unix path: /../src/espvr/core/src/api/mapi_pvr.cpp
5438298       0x52FB5A        Unix path: /../src/espvr/core/src/utility/PVR_File_Operand.cpp
5438798       0x52FD4E        Unix path: /../src/espvr/core/src/context/PVR_File_Root.cpp
5439894       0x530196        Unix path: /../src/espvr/core/src/context/PVR_Metadata.cpp
5441758       0x5308DE        Unix path: /../src/espvr/core/src/path/PVR_Path_Download.cpp
5443490       0x530FA2        Unix path: /../src/espvr/core/src/path/PVR_Path_DualDownload.cpp
5445230       0x53166E        Unix path: /../src/espvr/core/src/path/PVR_Path_ESPlayer.cpp
5445914       0x53191A        Unix path: /../src/espvr/core/src/path/PVR_Path_Manager.cpp
5447010       0x531D62        Unix path: /../src/espvr/core/src/path/PVR_Path_TSPlayer.cpp
5448770       0x532442        Unix path: /../src/espvr/core/src/context/PVR_Splitted_File.cpp
5449582       0x53276E        Unix path: /../src/espvr/core/src/context/PVR_Sys.cpp
5450354       0x532A72        Unix path: /../src/espvr/core/src/path/PVR_Thread.cpp
5452094       0x53313E        Unix path: /../src/espvr/core/src/path/PVR_Upload_State_Scan.cpp
5452634       0x53335A        Unix path: /../src/espvr/core/src/context/PVR_VideoParser.cpp
5453802       0x5337EA        Unix path: /../src/espvr/core/src/data_manager/PVR_Data_RingBuffer.cpp
5454258       0x5339B2        Unix path: /../src/espvr/core/src/context/PVR_File_IO_Read.cpp
5456690       0x534332        Unix path: /../src/espvr/core/src/context/PVR_File_IO_Write.cpp
5457670       0x534706        Unix path: /../src/espvr/core/src/path/PVR_Upload_State_188Normal.cpp
5458488       0x534A38        Unix path: /ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/infra/v2_0_60/src/pure.cxx
5458489       0x534A39        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/infra/v2_0_60/src/pure.cxx"
5458519       0x534A57        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/infra/v2_0_60/src/pure.cxx"
5458613       0x534AB5        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/services/memalloc/common/v2_0_60/src/kapi.cxx"
5458643       0x534AD3        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/services/memalloc/common/v2_0_60/src/kapi.cxx"
5460693       0x5352D5        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/Kappa/LIB_eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/memalloc/"
5460723       0x5352F3        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/Kappa/LIB_eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/memalloc/mfiximpl.inl"
5460741       0x535305        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/memalloc/mfiximpl.inl"
5461473       0x5355E1        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/Kappa/LIB_eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/memalloc/"
5461503       0x5355FF        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/Kappa/LIB_eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/memalloc/mvarimpl.inl"
5461521       0x535611        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCos_fileio_posix_fat_ntfs_jffs2_v3_c++_kappa_34kf_install/include/cyg/memalloc/mvarimpl.inl"
5462269       0x5358FD        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/language/c/libc/stdio/v2_0_60/src/common/setvbuf.cxx"
5462299       0x53591B        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/language/c/libc/stdio/v2_0_60/src/common/setvbuf.cxx"
5522696       0x544508        Unix path: /ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/language/c/libc/i18n/v2_0_60/src/locale.cxx
5522697       0x544509        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/language/c/libc/i18n/v2_0_60/src/locale.cxx"
5522727       0x544527        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/language/c/libc/i18n/v2_0_60/src/locale.cxx"
5523265       0x544741        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/language/c/libc/stdio/v2_0_60/src/input/fgetc.cxx"
5523295       0x54475F        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/language/c/libc/stdio/v2_0_60/src/input/fgetc.cxx"
5524333       0x544B6D        eCos RTOS string reference: "ecos-y/PERFORCE/THEALE/Uranus/eCospro/packages/language/c/libc/time/v2_0_60/src/strftime.cxx"
5524363       0x544B8B        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCospro/packages/language/c/libc/time/v2_0_60/src/strftime.cxx"
6055568       0x5C6690        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5A, dictionary size: 4194304 bytes, uncompressed size: 16384 bytes
7114983       0x6C90E7        Boot section Start 0x7040000 End 0x-FFF9
7564060       0x736B1C        YAFFS filesystem
```

I did tried unyaffs and unyaffs2 to extract but without any success, alsot tried  to extract those .7z files but they does not containt nothing. [Firmware](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B95UR9turb7DWEZ1UjMyRVBXMzg/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot extract files with unyaffs tools, because the firmware does not contain yaffs. The first compressed image is the bootloader, which displays the splash screen image. It seems that the image start address was found by binwalk correctly.

The second compressed image is an ecos image started at address `0x80000180`. You can analyse it with IDA or your favorite disassemble, which support MIPS in little endian.

Comment: How do you mean it starts at `0x80000180` when file is `0x78cb03` long ?

Comment: I mean it as a virtual address. If you want to analyse it, you have to set the starting offset to `0x80000180` and the absolute addresses will point to the right places.